# Select unique countries with more than one customer

Tags: sql, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I need to show the countries that have more than one individual.

Customers

```html
customer_id first_name  last_name   age country
1           John        Doe         31  USA
2           Robert      Luna        22  USA
3           David       Robinson    22  UK
4           John        Reinhardt   25  UK
5           Betty       Doe         28  UAE

So the query should return 
customer_id first_name  last_name   age country
1           John        Doe         31  USA
2           Robert      Luna        22  USA
3           David       Robinson    22  UK
4           John        Reinhardt   25  UK
```

I tried tis query but it didn't work.
**SELECT last_name, Country
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country
HAVING COUNT(Customer_id) > 1;**

The actual table can be found [here](https://www.programiz.com/sql/online-compiler/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following query. Thanks

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS C
WHERE C.COUNTRY IN (SELECT COUNTRY FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY COUNTRY HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a windowed count as a filter:

```
with c as (
  select *, Count(*) over(partition by country) cnt
  from Customers
)
select * 
from c
where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT country, COUNT(customer_id) AS Customers FROM Customers 
GROUP BY country
HAVING COUNT(customer_id) > 1
```

These two queries are similar in their objective, which is to identify unique countries with more than one customer. However, they differ in the columns selected in the `SELECT` statement.

The first query selects the last_name and Country columns, but it doesn't use any aggregation function on last_name, which might not give you the desired result. It is likely that you would encounter an error or get unexpected output due to the presence of last_name without an aggregate function.

The second query selects the country column and uses the COUNT aggregation function for the customer_id column, aliasing it as Customers. This query is more appropriate as it correctly utilizes the COUNT function to count the number of customers in each country.

For accurate results, it is advisable to use the second query as it is designed more appropriately for the specified task. Execute the second query in your SQL environment to obtain the desired results. If you have any more questions or need further assistance, please feel free to ask

Comment: I added some code-formatting to your post but it remains a bit unclear. You talk about *two* queries but only show *one*. Can you edit to clarify your answer?